# how after ndimage.find_object ... color features?

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy

I have a large image which after labeling has about 500 features. I know how to get them in the slices using find_object but I want to color them so I can see the result. Any quick suggestion for that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use matplotlib like this:

```
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = scipy.misc.imread('all_blobs.png',flatten=1)
im, number_of_objects = ndimage.label(im)
blobs = ndimage.find_objects(im)

plt.imsave('blobs.png', im)
for i,j in enumerate(blobs):
    plt.imsave('blob'+str(i)+'.png',im[j])
```

original image:

[image]

labelled image:

[image]

slices containing the blobs:

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: Is there any easy way to get the boundaries of these blobs?  For example, what if I wanted to trim out all the dark blue from those images?  My situation doesn't deal with images, but conceptually I want the coordinates of the outline of each 'object' that find_objects returns.

Comment: Also, do you know how to plot the slices containing the blobs back onto the original image? Maybe just a square outline around them?

Comment: Have a look to pymorph (pm) which have can do overlay as follow:    display = pm.overlay(dapi,green=cont)
subplot(111)
imshow(display)